# Particular Example of a Thom Space

Tags: algebraic-topology, vector-spaces, proof-explanation, vector-bundles, fiber-bundles

Let $V$ and $W$ be finite dimensional real vector spaces with an inner product, and let $mor(V,W)$ be the set of linear maps from $V$ to $W$ which preserves the inner product i.e. $f \in mor(V,W)$ is a linear isometry.

Let $\gamma_n(V,W)$ be the vector bundle over $mor(V,W)$ consisting of pairs $(f,x)$ such that $f \in mor(V,W)$ and $x \in \Bbb{R}^n \otimes \text{coker}(f) $.

Then let $mor_n(V,W)$ be the Thom space of $\gamma_n(V,W)$.

I was wondering if anyone could explain the proof of the following proposition.

**Proposition: The reduced mapping cone of the restriction $mor_0(\Bbb{R}\oplus V, W) \to mor_0(V,W)$ is homeomorphic to $mor_1(V,W)$.**

The proof (which can be found [here](https://ivv5hpp.uni-muenster.de/u/mweis_02/preprints/or.pdf) (Proposition 1.1)) says that

1) if $\dim(V) \geq dim(W)$ the homeomorphism is obvious. How?

For this is understand when $dim(V) < dim(W)$, $mor_0(V,W) = *$ But I don't see how this makes the homeomorphism between the mapping cylinder and $mor_1(V,W)$ obvious. For $dim(V)=dim(W)$ I see that $\gamma_n(V,V)=0$ so $mor_n(V,V)= \gamma_n(V,V)_+ = O(V)_+$. Again, I'm not seeing how this makes the required homeomorphism between the mapping cylinder and $mor_1(V,V)$ obvious. My guess is that it has something to do with $mor_0(V,V) \cong mor_1(V,V)$ but I'm not sure how.

2) It gives a proof for $\dim(V) < dim(W)$, in which it says that the mapping cone is a quotient of the space $[0, \infty] \times mor_o(\Bbb{R}\oplus V,W)$. How?

3)Moreover it says that the restriction map is onto. How? **[Answered]**

Comment: What does "preserve isometries" mean?

Comment: Sorry should say preserves the inner product, and I should say that $V,W$ are finite dimensional vector spaces with an inner product. Editing the post to include those!

Comment: if $\dim V>\dim W$ then there are no such maps, and if instead there is equality such maps are surjective.

Comment: That is what I had assumed. And in the case where there is equality $V \cong W$. That doesnt help me much with constructing the homeomorphism.

Comment: Well, if you had noticed that then I do not understand why you asked (1).

Comment: Because the homeomorphism still isn't obvious.

Comment: If $\dim V>\dim W$, the set $mor(V,W)$ is empty: what is $mor_0(V,W)$ in that case? If $\dim V=\dim W$, then the vector bundle $\gamma_n(V,W)$ is the zero vector bundle.

Comment: Since $mor_0(V,W) = mor(V,W)_+$, $mor_0(V,W)$ in the first case is just the basepoint $*$ Why is $\gamma_n(V,W)$ the zero vector bundle in the other case?

Comment: Haven't you tried to see what happens in an example?! Take $V=W=\mathbb R^2$ with the usual inner products: can you give me a non-zero element of $\gamma_n(v,W)$?

Comment: I've no idea how to even go about trying to do that! My guess would be that $mor(\Bbb{R}^2, \Bbb{R}^2) = O(2)$ because we can define such maps on where they send the basis elements of $\Bbb{R}^2$. The map will send $(0,1)$ to any point on the unit circle, and then send $(1,0)$ to any point on the unit circle 90 degrees from the image of $(0,1)$. Thus there are two possible choice for where $(1,0)$ is mapped to, specifically you get those where the determinant of the matrix made up of the sine/cosine coordinates are $1$ and those where the determinant is $-1$.

Comment: Im not sure what that tells me about $\gamma_n(\Bbb{R}^2, \Bbb{R}^2)$ though

Comment: Well you wrote yourself the definition of what $\gamma_n(\mathbb R^2,\mathbb R^2)$ is: a point there is a pair $(f,x)$  with $f:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R^2$ an isometry and $x$ an element of $\mathbb R^n\otimes\operatorname{coker} f$. Can you give me an element of $\gamma_n(\mathbb R^2,\mathbb R^2)$?

Comment: It is essentially **impossible** for you to prove anything about a bundle if you do not know what the bundle is, you know.

Comment: Would $(id, 0)$ be a point in $\gamma_n(\Bbb{R}^2, \Bbb{R}^2)$, since $id$ preserves inner products and $coker(id) = 0$ and $0 \in \{0\}$.

Comment: Ok. Now give me 5 other elements.

Comment: The map $(0,1) \mapsto (1,0)$, $(0,1) \mapsto (-1,0)$, $(0,1) \mapsto (0,-1)$ (basically every map that sends a basis element to a $\pm1$ multiple of a basis element?

Comment: That is the first component of the pairs, but I asked for elements of $\gamma_n(\mathbb R^2,\mathbb R^2)$, and they are pairs.

Comment: second component is always $0$ because the cokernel is always trivial. So $\gamma_n(\Bbb{R}^2, \Bbb{R}^2) = \{(f,0) : f \in mor(\Bbb{R}^2, \Bbb{R}^2)\} =mor(\Bbb{R}^2, \Bbb{R}^2)$.

Comment: And then what is the rank of the vector bundle $\gamma_n(\mathbb R^2,\mathbb R^2)$?

Comment: 2? or is it zero?

Comment: Well. I think you should probably read at this point your notes on what a vector bundle is and so on. You seem to be not very sure about the basics, so it does not a lot of sense to work on this problem right now.

Comment: The vector bundle is the map $p:\gamma_n(\mathbb R^2,\mathbb R^2)\to mor(\mathbb R^2,\mathbb R^2)$ which sends a pair $(f,v)$ to $f$, as you wrote in the question. The preimage of each point in the codomain of $p$ is a vector space: of what dimension?

Comment: Each $f$ has one preimage so rank of $p$ is one?

Comment: The rank of a vector bundle is the dimension of the vector spaces which preimages of points. what is the dimension of the vector space which is the preimage of a point in $mor(\mathbb R^2,\mathbb R^2)$?

Comment: I'm still sticking with the dimension being one, but I feel like I'm missing something basic. Each $(f,v)$ is mapped to $f$ so the preimage of $f$ has to just be $(f,v)$?

Comment: The fiber over $f$ is $\mathbb{R}^n\otimes\text{coker}(f)$ you said. If $f$ has trivial cokernel, then the fiber is the trivial vector space.

Comment: I didn’t know that was the fibre! My vector bundle knowledge is evidently not the best. Any suggestion of references for vector bundles. Also how does the vector bundle having rank zero relate to the Thom space?

Comment: you had no idea? But you're the one who said it! Anyway, the Thom space of a rank zero vector bundle is just the base again. Or maybe the base plus discrete basepoint? Since the disk bundle is just the total space = the base. And the sphere bundle is empty. quotient by empty space = add a point?

Comment: I'd never seen a vector bundle described as a pair until this paper. So in general a vector bundle is a par $(x,y)$ with $x$ in the base space and $y$ in the fibre over $x$? Furthermore, $mor_n(\Bbb{R}^2, \Bbb{R}^2)$ is just $mor(\Bbb{R}^2, \Bbb{R}^2)_+$? So we can clearly say that $mor_n(V,V) = mor(V,V)_+$ Thus $mor_0(V,V) \cong mor_1(V,V)$?

Comment: This is the essence of any fiber bundle: it locally has the structure of a Cartesian product. Just keep in mind that they are not always Cartesian products globally. There are fiber bundles with fiber $F$ and base $B$ other than $B\times F$. But it is often possible to describe a bundle as a subbundle of some trivial bundle with large ambient fiber. That’s what’s happening here I think.

Comment: In any case a bundle isn’t an ordered pair $(x,v)$. It is the space of all such points. Where $x$ is a point in the base, and $v$ is a point in the basepoint dependent fiber $F_x=p^{-1}(x).$

Comment: This has really helped! Thank you both so much!

Comment: You might like to look at the paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1101.4099v3 for some additional details that Weiss may have omitted. I believe Barnes was a student of his. I found some of his presentation much clearer. (see Pr. 4.5 in particular.)

Comment: Thanks! Still really struggling with the dimV< dimW case of this proposition! But I’ll get there